# Alter MySQL table with foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, alter

There are two tables news and language.
This is the original  table   in MySQL :

```
CREATE TABLE `news` (
`news_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fleet_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`channel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`effective_from` date NOT NULL,
`effective_to` date NOT NULL,
`news` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`news_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `language` (
`ietf_language_tag` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`endonym` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`exonym` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ietf_language_tag`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

/* Issue alter table command */

```
ALTER TABLE news
ADD ietf_language_tag varchar(5) NOT NULL,
ADD KEY (ietf_language_tag) ,
ADD CONSTRAINT news_fkey1 FOREIGN KEY (ietf_language_tag) REFERENCES   
language(ietf_language_tag) ON DELETE NO ACTION  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
```

/* getting error  */

Error:

> 14:57:51   ALTER TABLE news ADD ietf_language_tag varchar(5) NOT NULL, ADD KEY
>       (ietf_language_tag) , ADD CONSTRAINT news_fkey1 FOREIGN KEY (ietf_language_tag)
>       REFERENCES language(ietf_language_tag) ON DELETE NO ACTION  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
>       Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint 0.437 sec

Comment: By your sql, I didn`t get the same error as yours, but after I changed column type from varchar to int, it works, I`m not sure if your problem is same as mine, please try.

Answer (score 1):

### character set issue

Both `news` and `language` have different character set `latin1` for `news`, `utf8` for `language`.

### FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS

Even though character sets are same, you will get an error if you have records on `news` table as follows.

> > ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_name`.`#sql-296_72a7a`, CONSTRAINT `news_fkey1` FOREIGN KEY (`ietf_language_tag`) REFERENCES `language` (`ietf_language_tag`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

this problem can be fixed with `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;`

```
mysql> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE news
    -> ADD ietf_language_tag varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    -> ADD KEY (ietf_language_tag) ,
    -> ADD CONSTRAINT news_fkey1 FOREIGN KEY (ietf_language_tag) REFERENCES
    -> language(ietf_language_tag) ON DELETE NO ACTION  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```